# Instagram reels downloader using Python

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-story

So basically, for one of my client, I need to create an application which is supposed to download reels from instagram. I've tried many modules and packages, but none of them are working. Following are some of them:

1. instascrape
2. instagrapi
3. instaloader

Following is one of the code I've tried, but couldn't find the result.

```
google_reel.scrape()
SESSIONID = "MY_SESSION_ID"
headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.74 Safari/537.36 Edg/79.0.309.43",
"cookie":f'sessionid={SESSIONID};'
}

google_reel=Reel(link)
google_reel.scrape(headers=headers)
google_reel.download(fp=f".\\reel{int(time.time())}.mp4")
```

However, following code is working which tried to fetch the dp of instagram username & downloads it.

```
bot = instaloader.Instaloader()
username = "IG_USERNAME"
print(bot.download_profile(username, profile_pic_only=True))
```

Actually, I need to create a website that can download reels, videos, posts, etc, and for my personal project too, I'm developing it in Python. You can also suggest this in PHP. I've searched in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093007/python-downloader) too but it was also not working. Kindly suggest me something.